# R: Lubridate Failing to Convert Character to Numeric

Tags: r, date, character, lubridate

I'm new to R - and searched old post for an answer but failed to come across anything that resolved my issue.

I pulled in a csv with the time a trip started in the mdy h:mm:ss format, but it is currently recognized as a character. I've tried to use `mdy_hms(c("11/1/2020 0:05:00","11/1/2020 7:29:00","11/1/2020 14:04:00"))`
as well as
`as.Date(parse_date_time(dc_biketrips$started_at, c(mdy_hms)))` to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could fix this?

UPDATE: I also tried to use `date <-mdy_hms(c("11/1/2020 0:05:00","11/1/2020 7:29:00","11/1/2020 14:04:00")) str(date)`but this also did not work

[attempt to use date <-mdy_hms(C("11/1/2020 0:05:00"etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJrcC.png)

[image of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLUPP.png)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `as.POSIXct`:

```r
started_at <- c("11/1/2020 0:05:00","11/1/2020 7:29:00","11/1/2020 14:04:00")

as.POSIXct(started_at, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS")
#> [1] "2020-11-01 00:05:00 CET" "2020-11-01 07:29:00 CET"
#> [3] "2020-11-01 14:04:00 CET"
```

**EDIT**

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

started_at <- c("11/1/2020 0:05:00","11/1/2020 7:29:00","11/1/2020 14:04:00")
```

1. Both `as.POSIXct` and `lubridate::mdy_hms` return an object of class `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

```
class(as.POSIXct(started_at, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS"))
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
class(mdy_hms(started_at))
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

2. Not sure what you expect. When I run your code everything works fine except that we end up with 0 obs after filtering for `week < 15` as all the dates in the example data are from week 44:

```
dc_biketrips <- data.frame(
  started_at
)

dc_biketrips <- dc_biketrips %>% 
  mutate(started_at = as.POSIXct(started_at, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS"),
         interval60 = floor_date(started_at, unit = "hour"), 
         interval15 = floor_date(started_at, unit = "15 mins"), 
         week = week(interval60), 
         dotw = wday(interval60, label=TRUE)) 
dc_biketrips
#>            started_at          interval60          interval15 week dotw
#> 1 2020-11-01 00:05:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00   44   So
#> 2 2020-11-01 07:29:00 2020-11-01 07:00:00 2020-11-01 07:15:00   44   So
#> 3 2020-11-01 14:04:00 2020-11-01 14:00:00 2020-11-01 14:00:00   44   So

dc_biketrips %>% 
  filter(week < 15)
#> [1] started_at interval60 interval15 week       dotw      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @stefan ! This didn't seem to work either, as I'm trying to create time interval bins - and did not have any results when running the following code: Bike_20 <- dc_biketrips %>%
  mutate(interval60 = floor_date(mdy_hms(started_at), unit = "hour"),
         interval15 = floor_date(mdy_hms(started_at), unit = "15 mins"),
         week = week(interval60),
         dotw = wday(interval60, label=TRUE)) %>%
  filter(week < 15)

Comment: @Marie. Not sure what's the issue. Both as.POSIXct and mdy_hms work fine. It's only the filtering which drops all observations. See my edit.

Comment: Ah understood. Issue resolved- thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

The first of your two options works:

```r
library(lubridate)
date <-mdy_hms(c("11/1/2020 0:05:00","11/1/2020 7:29:00","11/1/2020 14:04:00"))
str(date)
# POSIXct[1:3], format: "2020-11-01 00:05:00" "2020-11-01 07:29:00" "2020-11-01 14:04:00"
```

How were your data "pulled in"?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I pulled in the data with read.csv. I tried to use your suggestion (see update w/ image above), though it also did not seem to work as the column is still classed as a character, and when I Tried to create time interval bins, I get 0 results (with Bike_20 <- dc_biketrips %>%
  mutate(interval60 = floor_date(mdy_hms(started_at), unit = "hour"),
         interval15 = floor_date(mdy_hms(started_at), unit = "15 mins"),
         week = week(interval60),
         dotw = wday(interval60, label=TRUE)) %>%
  filter(week < 15)